# Как определить переменную с содержимым из масива с ключом 0

Tags: php

У меня проблема в том что:
Нужно строку разбить через пробелы.
Затем первое слово вставить в переменную.
Если я сделаю так:

```
<?php
$first = "/tp player";
$second = explode(" ", $first);
$third = $second[0]; //ошибка и переменная остаётся пустой.
```

Я не могу понять, как из массива достать содержимое с ключом '0' и при этом вставить это содержимое в переменную?
Если проще, то мне нужно проверить, если в начале сообщения есть "/" то запомнить комманду а не всё сообщение или же комманду с её аргументами.
P.S.
Ошибка точно возникает НЕ из-за оссобености бинарника PHP или ОС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым..
array_shift() который возвращает нулевой так скажем элемент в массиве.
P.S.
Сам если честно не пойму, каждый раз как я публикую свой вопрос тут я очень скоро сам нахожу решение.

Comment: Это хорошо! Значит, вы учитесь! С Новым Годом!

Comment: Я знаю, спасибо, вас тоже с новым годом!